# Add a blank slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I add a blank slide at some specific place? For example second position.

Comment: Just "ActivePresentation.Slides.Add 2,  ppLayoutBlank" would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub InsertSlide()
    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim lPosition As Long
    Dim oSl As Slide

    ' What layout/master should the new slide use?
    ' Designs(1) = the first SlideMaster in the presentation
    ' CustomLayouts(1) = a Title layout
    ' To get other layout index numbers, look at the layout gallery
    ' in PPT, count left to right, top to bottom
    Set oLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
    lPosition = 3

    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(lPosition, oLayout)
    With oSl
        ' do whatever you need to with the slide
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(lPosition, oLayout) gives me Slides (unknow member): Integer out of range. 3 is not in the valide range of 1 to 1 Error.

Comment: As written, the macro adds a new slide 3. You'll need to edit it to suit your needs (presumably a presentation with only one slide, IWC, try using 2 instead of 3).